# mPDF Error: Doesn´t work on Server

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am using mPDF to create a pdf document and to save it. It works fine on my localhost but when I try it on the server it is not creating (Saving) the pdf document. I came to know that I don´t have enough permissions (777) to the project folder. I tried to change the permissions by right-clicking the folder >Properties> Security. It doesn´t work to change the permissions for my user.

I have full access to only on my c: and so am thinking to save the pdf document on my desktop like C:/users/Novice/pdf

Here´s my code

```
include_once("sample_gen_pdf/mpdf.php");

        $mpdf=new mPDF( ); 

        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);

        $mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/pdf/'.$filename.'.pdf', 'F');
```

It works fine on the localhost but not on the server and so I need to save the pdf on my desktop. Any help on my code is much more appreciated.

When I execute the above code on the server it´s returning me an error as

**mPDF Error: Unable to create output file: /project/pdf/filename**